# Sum of every 4th column in a row in Excel to end of row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016, sumproduct

I have a VBA Code that adds 4 new columns (Quantity Used, Scrapped or no Bill, Invoiced, Revenue) every time a new sheet is added in a workbook. I am needing to create a formula that adds every 4th column together starting at column S to the end of the row as the end column is always changing. Below is the formula I have created, but I get #VALUE!. Can someone please help. Below is a link to the sample worksheet.

=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($S13:$XN13)-0,4)=0)*($S13:$XN13))

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m_aZJyUdShydn53Puvb2G38g5C1YCvCJ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (array formula, so Ctrl + Shift + Enter):

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($S$13:$XN$13),4)=0,$S$13:XN13,""))
```

I couldn't change your array formula, therefore in the picture I took row 71.

[image]

This formula works, but it assumes that you have no empty cells in the row you are checking (array formula, so Ctrl + Shift + Enter).

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN($S13:$XN13)-0,4)=0)*($S13:$XN13))
```

[image]

---

Both formulas assumes that you don't have any #VALUE or #N/A values in your week data (i.e. no error values in range `$S13:$XN13`).

---

For other columns, change the number of the cluster for the MOD, [explanation](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T009203_Summing_Every_Fourth_Cell_in_a_Row.html).

So to SUM Column G, we change the `=0` to `=3`:

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($S$13:$XN$13),4)=3,$S$13:XN13,""))
```

Column H

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($S$13:$XN$13),4)=1,$S$13:XN13,""))
```

Column J

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($S$71:$XN$71),4)=2,$S$71:XN71,""))
```

Comment: The first one worked, but how do I replicate it for columns G,H, and J? Which number would I adjust.

=SUM(IF(MOD(COLUMN($S$13:$XN$13),4)=0,$S$13:XN13,""))

Column F is the sum of all the "Man Hours"
Column G is the sum of all the "Quantity Installed"
Column H is the sum of all the "Invoiced"
Column J is the sum of all the "Revenue"

Comment: I believe I figured it out is it the "=0" that I adjust?

Comment: Exactly!! is the `=0`, since it adjust the position in cluster of of the group that should be sum. Feel free to ask if you have any more questions :)!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help!